# Per-role settings with Capistrano

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm currently using the multistage extension, but within each stage I have a role that requires a different :user, and :deploy_to path.

Example deploy/production.rb:

```
role :web, 'myhost1'
role :queue, 'myhost2'
```

Both servers need a checked out release, but the :web role uses `/var/www/html` where :queue uses `/home/username/path/to/releases`, and both use different SSH user.

I also have a staging and qa stage configured similarly (both have :web and :queue roles on different servers).

How can I set these roles-specific options?

Answer (score 2):

you simply specify role-specific options as a hash argument to role:

```
role :web, 'myhost1', {
  :user => 'bill',
  :deploy_to => '/var/www/html'
}
```

for more flexibility, try https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension

Comment: I believe this does not work. `cap deploy:check` `deploy:setup` and `deploy:update` appear to ignore a configuration value set in the role attributes.

Comment: for more flexibility, try https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension

Comment: As I mentioned, I am using multistage, but need additional configuration granularity for each role within a stage.